# Highlighting level low with high level inspections

Tags: phpstorm, code-inspection

It there possible to have :

*a low level highlightning inspections for working with editor*

**BUT**

*launch inspections manually with high level(lot of rules inspections activate)*

---

It seems that this 2 functionnality are linked. So low hightlighting activate low inspections manually.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no such a way, Hector (the icon) affects batch inspections running as well.
Please submit this as a usability issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=WI